# Does Firestore charge for Query Executions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to figure out why I am getting significantly more reads than expected on Firestore. This is the function I executed **once** from my app:

```
docs = await getDocs(
                query(
                    collection(db, "openTenders"),
                    where("locationState", "==", queryParams.l.toUpperCase()),
                    orderBy("closeTimestamp"),
                    startAfter(lastTender),
                    limit(20)
                )
            );
```

I am limiting it to return 20 documents, but am still getting 325 reads.
[image]

I am wondering if Firebase charges a read per document in an index query? If someone has some insight into this, or if I should go back and and diagnose why my app is behaving this way.
Thanks!

Comment: Firestore doesn't need to read the document to determine if it matches the condition in the query, as it uses indexes for that. The code you show only gets charged a document read for each document returns (unless there are 0 results, in which case it'll charge 1 document read for the query itself). So the charges are likely coming from somewhere else. For example: do you have the document viewer in the console open? Usage by the Firestore console is also charged, and leads to many more document reads than most devs realize.

Comment: Wow that was exactly what it was. Thanks for the info. I'll try not to click that as much :D

Comment: Good to head @OMGitsRob. And thanks Doug for finding the duplicate, which was next on my list. :)